# distance between given set and some other sets - sql server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a table which contains the item and category ids:

```
create table SomeTable (
    ItemId int,
    CategoryId int
)
```

Given some category ids (Set X) I would like to determine all item ids that share at least one category id and some stats for each of these item ids:

A – Number of category ids of item id that are not in set x
B – Number of category ids shared between item id and set x
C – Number of category ids in set x but which are not associated with item id

I have written some tsql code which involves a cross join and several ctes plus left joins. It works but is fairly slow.

I am sure someone must have encountered a similar problem. I would provide the code but the above description is simplified. Thanks.

Comment: sorry 2005 and I pass it via nhibernate as strings so the first thing i do is determine the category ids from the strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a couple of ideas. (I don't know how they'll compare performance wise with what you have already. Left for you to benchmark.)

```
set nocount on;

-- create a sample table
declare @T table ( ItemId int identity(1,1), CategoryId int );
insert @T values ( 100 );
insert @T values ( 100 );
insert @T values ( 100 );
insert @T values ( 100 );
insert @T values ( 100 );
insert @T values ( 200 );
insert @T values ( 200 );
insert @T values ( 300 );
insert @T values ( 300 );
insert @T values ( 300 );
insert @T values ( 300 );
insert @T values ( 500 );
insert @T values ( 500 );
insert @T values ( 500 );
insert @T values ( 600 );
insert @T values ( 700 );
insert @T values ( 800 );
insert @T values ( 800 );
insert @T values ( 800 );
insert @T values ( 900 );


-- grab some CategoryIDs to work with
declare @X table ( CategoryId int );
insert @X
    select CategoryID=200 union
    select CategoryID=400 union
    select CategoryID=600 union
    select CategoryID=800 


-- A. Number of category ids of item id that are not in set x
select distinct t.CategoryID from @T t
where not exists(select 1 from @X x where t.CategoryID = x.CategoryID)

-- or, using the set difference operator
select CategoryID from @T
except
select CategoryID from @X


-- B. Number of category ids shared between item id and set x
select distinct x.CategoryID from @X x
join @T t on t.CategoryID = x.CategoryID;

-- or, using set intersection
select CategoryID from @T
intersect
select CategoryID from @X


-- C. Number of category ids in set x but which are not associated with item id 
select distinct x.CategoryID from @X x
where not exists(select 1 from @T t where t.CategoryID = x.CategoryID)

-- or, using the set difference operator
select CategoryID from @X
except
select CategoryID from @T
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with CTE is they are run each time they are referenced and do not have constraints. Load your Set X into a temporary table with primary key on ID. Then run the same joins against the temporary and you should see big performance gain. SQL does much better when joins are based on primary keys.